# Single container of different objects that all inherited the same class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual, superclass

I'm trying to accomplish something but am unsure if it's even possible.

The quick idea is, I'm writing a game and want to have a single array (or vector) of different monsters.  Every class that inherits the main class Monster simply overrides its functions (but doesn't add any new ones).

Then, when I go through the list of monsters, I can just call the same functions that all of them have.

Here's some code to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Monster
{
    public:
        int hp;  //hit points
        int atp; //attack power
        int def; //defense

        bool attacking;
        bool defending;

        virtual void attack();
        virtual void defend();
};

void Monster::attack()
{}

void Monster::defend()
{}



class Goblin: public Monster
{
    public:
        virtual void attack() override;
        virtual void defend() override;
};

void Goblin::attack()
{
    //Goblin's attacking patterns
}

void Goblin::defend()
{
    //Goblin's defending patterns
}


class Orc: public Monster
{
    public:
        virtual void attack() override;
        virtual void defend() override;
};

void Orc::attack()
{
    //Orc's attacking patterns
}

void Orc::defend()
{
    //Orc's defending patterns
}




int main(void)
{
    //This is where I'm not sure what to do:

    //Initialize monsters.  Make some Goblins, some Orcs
    int num_monsters = 10;
    Monster* monster_list;
    monster_list = new Monster[num_monsters];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_monsters; i++)
    {
        int which = rand() % 2;
        switch (which)
        {
            case 0:  //Goblin
               monster_list[i] = new Goblin;                   
               break;
            case 1:  //Orc
               monster_list[i] = new Orc;                   
               break;
        }
    }

    bool quit = false;
    while (quit == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_monsters; i++)
        {
            if (monster_list[i].attacking == true)
                monster_list[i].attack();
            if (monster_list[i].defending == true)
                monster_list[i].defend();                
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that illustrates what I'm trying to do.
I know this doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to make it work.
Thanks for any advice on this!

Comment: You need a vector of `Monster *`s.

Comment: The concept is both polymorphism and covariance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: There are two links in that comment above.

Comment: try: `std::vector<Monster*> monsters;` Then you can do: `monsters.push_back(new Goblin);`

Comment: What's with everyone completely ignoring smart pointers?

Comment: As @chris mentioned, using a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>>` is a safer and better solution for many reasons, but the real point is using a pointer, the actual method to be executed can be looked up in a virtual table of the class. The compiler handles this for you.

Comment: The smart pointers are definitely the way to go, however the question he's asking is already introducing several new concepts that I'm guessing he is currently unaware of and will only serve to further his confusion instead of help him further. Smart pointer syntax is more foreign than traditional pointers I'm sure.

Comment: Since there's no need for shared ownership, using `std::unique_ptr` would be better. @NickSavage, Then it can replace teaching how to manage the memory manually that the OP doesn't seem to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The vector of Monster* did the trick and it's working.  
@Steve I saw that there were two links.  Thanks.  I've heard the terms and know what they are on a base level, but it looks like I have some reading to do.  Good stuff!

Thanks all.

Comment: Hard to tell if he's handling the memory correctly or not, we have little code to base that assumption off of.

Comment: Correct in that I've never heard of `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.  I'll look them up and do some reading on them.  Probably good things to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use a vector of pointers to a base class.

```
std::vector<Monster*> monsters;

monsters.push_back(new FireDragon());
monsters.push_back(new IceDragon());
```

Then you'll be able to iterate through the monsters vector and call a common method.

```
for(auto monster = monsters.begin(); monster != monsters.end(); monster++)
{
    (*monster)->attack();
}
```

The classes:

```
class Monster {
public:
    virtual ~Monster() {}
    virtual void attack() = 0;
};

class FireDragon : public Monster {
public:
    ~FireDragon();
    void attack()
    {
        std::cout << "Fire breath!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class IceDragon : public Monster {
public:
    ~IceDragon();
    void attack()
    {
        std::cout << "Ice breath!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

As a side note be sure to create virtual destructors in the derived classes or else the base class' destructor will be called.

ETA: Here is the implementation with smart pointers:

```
/*
Use std::unique_ptr<Monster> if your implementation doesn't need to pass the
monster objects around
*/

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>> monsters;

/*
Use std::make_unique<FireDragon>() if using unique_ptr
*/

monsters.push_back(std::make_shared<FireDragon>());
monsters.push_back(std::make_shared<IceDragon>());

for(auto monster : monsters)
{
    monster->attack();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This took care of it.  And good call on the virtual destructors.  Makes sense, but I wouldn't have thought of it.

Comment: On a separate note, the for loop you created gives me errors:

`'monster' does not name a type`   

`expected ';' before 'monster'`   

`'monster' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @JustinLloyd, Compile with C++11.

Comment: - `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Monster>>` would be better.
- the for range may be written `for (auto&& monster : monsters) { monster->attack(); }
- you may add directly `virtual ~Monster() {}` in replacement of the side note.
- you should remove the `void` parameter: `void attack()` is valid C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 All valid points however I tried to cater the answer to the skill level I perceived the question at. I feel the code I offered is much easier on the eyes for a beginner than the "best practice". Both versions will do what the poster requires however it might be easier to understand what's actually going on if you offer up a simpler approach. You don't learn to fly a 747 in your first pilot training seminar, you use a simpler interface first.

Comment: @JustinLloyd I would appreciate an accepted answer if this helped with your problem

Comment: @Nick Savage Forgot about that. Accepted!